# Processor Choice for Deep Learning PC

Tags: processor, intel

I'm planning to build a PC for deep learning and computer vision, but I'm really confused about which processor I should get. I've read too many articles about it, and still couldn't decide. Currently, I am considering the 10600K or 3700X: The 3700X fits better in my budget, but I am worried AMD might cause compatibility issues when running Python or C. My GPU will be the RTX 3060. I also use Android Studio, etc. Which processor would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I have a zen 2 based CPU and did'nt have issues running any programs (except a mac vm, but that's a different story). the 3700x has more cores (i think thats better for machine learning) and zen 2 can run Linux (which is written in C). I never had issues running python on a zen 2 based laptop, and I even managed to run Android studio on my ryzen.

Conclusion: the 3700x should be a bit better and should be compatible

Answer (score 0):

I have an i7-10700f and love it!  If you can afford a little bit more, I would highly recommend it.  It works well with python.